# Is this sentence grammatically correct - voice use?

Tags: word-order, questions, do-support

The sentence is "Which major you selected in the candidate information form?"

My colleague is arguing that the sentence doesn't make sense because "if you read it aloud, it sounds weird."

His/her suggestion is to use "Which major did you select in the candidate information form?"

Although I am sure his/her suggestion is correct but please tell me if there is a grammatical error in my sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your colleague is quite right.

The issue is not the voice — both versions are in the active voice — but the word order: in a question, we *invert* the subject ("you") and auxiliary verb ("did"). ("You selected" doesn't contain an auxiliary verb, but when we need subject–auxiliary inversion, we treat it as if it were "you did select", resulting in "did you select". And similarly, when we need to negate it, we say "you didn't select" or "you did not select".)